# Civicrm for Joomla capabilities Blog

Tags: joomla, newsletter

I saw a blog today "WordPress or Drupal: Which CMS Should Your Association Use to integrate with CiviCRM for Your Website and Member Portal?"

Joomla is equally impressive specially with its Joomla 4 release.

Can we expand this article to include Joomla capabilities that Civicrm users can benefit from?

Joomla4Accessibility

Whatever size your site is, accessibility is a must, and from the start, Joomla 4 delivers best in class accessibility. The layout, contrast and infrastructure all have accessibility built-in so all your visitors will benefit. We have aimed for W3C Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.1 (with AA compliance)

Joomla4Design

A redesigned administration area speeds content creation. Improved media manager and editor updates give you the power to design and build amazing websites. Article templates help you and your colleagues keep to the page design

Joomla4Emails

Deliver customized emails that welcome and inform your website's audience effectively! With the new email template system, it's easier than ever to make the emails your site sends be on message and on brand. Now you can take your site to the next level when communicating with your customers.

Joomla4Search

Search is a boost to any site. It allows your visitors to hone in on the areas they are interested in, increasing engagement and improving your sites ranking. So when it comes to search look no further, Joomla 4 smart search has many improvements over previous Joomla search and is the best to date.

Joomla4SEO

Get to the top of any search engine fast with Joomla 4. It takes care of SEO, so you can focus on getting your great content noticed. SEO built into the architecture of the page means you get the correct page structure without any additional extensions.

Joomla4Security

Running a site with state of the art well-written code helps you stay ahead when it comes to security. With many architecture changes designed to maximize security and keep hackers out, you can be assured that moving to Joomla 4 is a wise choice. The benefits are countless when it comes to ensuring you and your clients data are as well protected as they can be.

Joomla4Speed

With Joomla 4 you benefit from the increased performance. Speed is one of the top factors in conversions whether your site is eCommerce or you need to grow your subscriptions. Joomla 4 gives your site the boost it needs.

Comment: Blog posts are contributed by partners. clearly that partner does not use Joomla so did not make the comparison

Comment: as for the rest of the above 'question' i am a bit curious - are you asking if the above can be pasted in to the blog?

Comment: how is "Joomla4Emails: Deliver customized emails that welcome and inform your website's audience effectively" to a civi based system where civi is sending the emails?

Answer (score 0):

My thinking was very simple that it would be helpful if we have a comparative good info. on Drupal, Joomla 4 and Wordpress forwider users of Civicrm.

I didn't think past this intention/thought.

Comment: You're right that Joomla doesn't get much focus here but it is a very capable platform.  The vast  majority of CiviCRM capability is CRM-agnostic but being able to create your own form linked to Civi is an attractive feature of Drupal (Webform) and WP (Caldera). Something similar for J4 would make it more likely to be considered.